# how do I link my src/app.js file to babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

src/app.js file keeps showing it doesn't exist in git bash

I tried adding quotations
babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets="env,react"
instead of this

babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react but it still did not work

Answer (score -1):

Consider looking at the .gitignor file, please. if you put src folder or src/app in .gitignor then it's not shown in git bash

Comment: Thanks. But while I was waiting for help to arrive all I did was to move the src file into the root directory and it worked.